# GCC Cross-Compiler Cygwin64: GFDL license tm.texi

Tags: c++, gcc, gnu

Following this tutorial: http://wiki.osdev.org/GCC_Cross-Compiler.
(I'm also using Cygwin64.)
When running "make install-gcc" i recieve the message:

```
Verify that you have permission to grant a GFDL license for all
new text in tm.texi, then copy it to ../../gcc-4.9.0/gcc/doc/tm.texi.
Makefile:2227: recipe for target 's-tm-texi' failed
make[2]: *** [s-tm-texi] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/c/cygwin64/home/Demx/build/gcc'
Makefile:4038: recipe for target 'install-gcc' failed
make[1]: *** [install-gcc] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/c/cygwin64/home/Demx/build'
Makefile:2187: recipe for target 'install' failed
make: *** [install] Error 2
```

Where is this tm.texi and how do I verify that I have permission to grant a GFDL license? Or is there another root to the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *shouldn't* have to worry about anything if you're not modifying GCC; this looks like an FSF-copyright-related problem.

This looks like a timestamp-related problem in the build system. Sometimes generated files are shipped alongside their sources, and depending on which order they were (extracted from the tarball OR checked out from the repo) they may or may not be regenerated by 'make'.

(side note: I looked at the relevant Makefile, and it had special cases for both non-ASCII systems *and* for ASCII systems that didn't understand '\r')